# imshow() doesnt update its content c++

Tags: c++, opencv, imshow

i am trying to show an image based on a number i manually enter [0 or 1], after that it chooses an image randomly from 20 images in a folder to be shown.
here is the code

```
stringstream ss;
string fullfileName;
int x;
int pic = 0;
namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
while (1)
{
    Mat img;
    pic = 0;
    cin >> x;
    if (x == 0)
    {
        pic = rand() % ((10 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    }
    else if (x == 1)
    {
        pic = rand() % ((20 - 11) + 1) + 11;
    }


    ss << "C:/Users/abed/Desktop/Opencv/test/" << pic << ".jpg";
    ss >> fullfileName;
    img = imread(fullfileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    imshow("MyWindow", img);
    char key = (char)waitKey(20);
    if (key == 27)
        break;

}
return 0;
```

my problem is : the imshow() only renders the first image chosen , regardless of the new value of the image Path.
thank you .

Comment: You've checked and you're sure the path is changing? Also, that all images can be loaded?

Comment: Yes , I did put some "cout" to check if they do change , and everything changes ,path to the images is correct and all of them can be loaded .the imshow() views the first IMG loaded and remain showing it.

Answer (score 2):

stringstream does not reset itself. It will keep appending new values to the existing one. I suggest you either make ss and fullfileName scoped variables i.e. move them inside the loop, OR reset the ss variable just before current iteration ends, such as ss.str(""); ss.clear()

Comment: Thank you very much , it worked like a charm when I added ss.clear(); at the end of the loop